# EditText: how to delete characters obtained from a Json

Tags: android, json

Is there any way I can remove characters from an EditText brought from a JSONObject response? Example: 2019-02-10T00: 00: 00 and only present the chain in this way: 2019-02-10

Answer (score 2):

```
String yourJsonDateString =  "2019-02-10T00: 00: 0";    
Date yourJsonDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.ffffff").parse(yourJsonDateString);    
String newDateString = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(yourJsonDate);

// Or Combine everything to :   
 String newDateString = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.ffffff").parse(yourJsonDateString));
```

Comment: Neat answer Chipo, wagona

Comment: erro: Illegal pattern character 'T', By integrating the code

Comment: You need to find a date format or pattern that matches your input date. You can Google, there is plenty of them.